Creating custom bot for an Discord Guild
I have seen several discord bots that have the option to customize some details of the bot (Name, Avatar, ...), some examples are MEE6, ProBot and some others.

What I would like to know is how to do it, since all the ideas I've had either make no sense, or simply don't work.
-- Things i've tried

I have tried to modify the bot member from the guild <guild>.members.me.setAvatar(), but this does not work.

I had thought that maybe they were using Discord's shards, but in that case, the changes would not only be reflected on that server, but also on all servers that make up that shard.



They are using individual isolated instances of the bot for each server.
To customize bot details (name, avatar, etc.) for each server, bots like MEE6 and ProBot run individual instances of the bot for each server.
Each instance is isolated, often using Docker containers, and loads its configuration from a database. Here’s how it works:

Individual Instances: Each bot instance is a separate process/container, ensuring changes are server-specific.
Configuration Management: Server-specific settings (name, avatar) are stored in a database.
Dynamic Loading: On startup, each bot instance loads its unique configuration from the database.

This approach allows each server to have a uniquely customized bot without affecting other servers. Using guild.members.me.setAvatar() or sharding won't achieve this, as they don't support per-server customization of bot identities.
So what you could do is:

Use a database for your bot application to store the bot's configuration.
Rewrite the bots application code (I hope you have it already like this) to login via the environment variables.
Create a docker image of your discord bot application.
Write a manager for automated starting/stopping of your constainer instances or start a container instance of your created docker image with your login token as environment variable.
Voilà! You now have an isolated instance of your bot.

